# Error when running gtk-redshift

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, brightness

I'm getting this error when I run `gtk-redshift` from the CLI (it just doesn't start if I start it from the GUI):

```
(process:3862): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_instance_get_private: assertion `instance != NULL && instance->g_class != NULL' failed
```

If I run `redshift`, I also get the same error as above, followed by this:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm running redshift version 1.7 and Xubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may need create a config file to avoid the crash..

Create a file named redshift.conf and save it into `~/.config/redshift.conf`. Here you have an example to create the [config file](http://jonls.dk/redshift/):

```
; Global settings
[redshift]
temp-day=5700
temp-night=3500
transition=1
gamma=0.8:0.7:0.8
location-provider=manual
adjustment-method=vidmode

; The location provider and adjustment method settings
; are in their own sections.
[manual]
lat=-34.6
lon=-58.3

;screen
[vidmode]
screen=0
```

To know the coordinates for your city you can use [itouchmap](http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html). Just search for your place and write down the numbers. 
eg: My city *Buenos Aires* is `lat=-34.6` and `lon=-58.3`

Once you have created the `redshift.conf` file, run the application and see if it works. You can find additional information about commands, config file, values on the [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) website...

Comment: @Roman Raguet: Thanks! I just want to add that this worked for Lubuntu (my version is 13.10). It seems the name of the file to be created should be "redshift.conf"

Comment: It worked for me after just creating an empty config file: `touch .config/redshift.conf`

Answer (score 0):

You can also just run it directly from the command line, no configuration needed:

```
redshift -l manual -l "52.05:-1.05" -t 5000:1100
```

This sets the position to manual (instead of using geoclue), and use the coordinates to set the latitude (north-south) to 52.05, and the longitude (east-west) to -1.05. You can find your position (though, a position nearby will do) manually using Google Maps, or similar:
 [image: a wood some distance away]

To stop it you can use

```
killall redshift
```

For more info, run `redhsift -h`.